# why does getsizeof a float num return 16 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

```
>>> x=float(12.345)
>>> x
12.345
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
16
>>> sys.getsizeof(12.345)
16
```

Here 16 is of the unit of byte?
But in the document it's of 64 bits the float

python 3.5.1 32bits
Windows 7 64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the size of a float in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216088/how-to-check-the-size-of-a-float-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

`sys.getsizeof()` returns the memory size of an instance of the `float` type. In addition to the 8 bytes used by the 64-bit IEEE representation of a float, additional memory is used for reference count, a pointer to type information, etc.

Comment: Nitpick: in this case, you could lose the `etc.`. At least for CPython, "value, refcount and type pointer" is an exhaustive list of what's stored for a float.

Answer (score 0):

The memory space consumed by a python variable depends on the what version of python you have ie. 32 bit or 64 bit platform.

Coming to float representation.
A float in 32 bit python consumes 16 bytes of memory while for 64 bit it consumes 24 byte of memory.