# are numpys dtypes kept even for non-numpy multiplications/divisions/sums?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on a simple simulator for a radio frequency application and have to deal with very low complex numbers. During the process I have a Matrix like `np.array([[A,B],[C,D]], dtype=np.clongdouble)` which ensures the necessary "resolution(?)". However, I have to do stuff like

```
den = A+B/z0+C*z0+D
s11 = A+B/z0-C*z0-D)/den
s12 = 2*(A*D-B*C)/den
s21 = 2/den
s22 = (-A+B/z0-C*z0+D)/den
```

I think `Z0` is of type `double` since it's calculated without numpy.

Now I wonder: Do I have to do the calculations of `den` etc with numpy to achieve/keep resolution or are the 'normal' calculations sufficient enough?

Comment: Python's floating-point numbers are usually 64-bit floating-point numbers, nearly equivalent to np.

Comment: Terminology: I think what you mean by "resolution" is what we call "precision"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python's complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) are represented *"as a pair of machine-level double precision floating point numbers"*.
This is typically 2 x 64 = 128 bits.

[NumPy's `clongdouble`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.clongdouble) are represented as a pair of machine-level *"extended-precision floating-point numbers"*.
This is typically 2 x 80 = 160 bits.

However, what [NumPy provides for `long double`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) (as per @WarrenWeckesser's comment) is platform and compiler dependent.

Therefore, the datatype you are using from NumPy may (or may not) have higher precision.

To force a number to have a specific precision, you can just cast it with [`np.array(..., dtype=...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8216088/5218354):

```py
import numpy as np


a = 1.0j
b = np.array(a, dtype=np.clongdouble)
print(b.dtype, b.nbytes)
# complex256 32
```

Note that the names here are a bit misleading as the number of bits refer to the alignment and not necessarily to the number of bits actually used for the data.

However, you do not need to do any specific casting for the above formulae to work, as the result of an operation with a higher precision and a lower precision operand would result in a higher precision result:

```py
c = np.array(a)
print(c.dtype, c.nbytes)
# complex128 16

d = b + c
print(d.dtype, d.nbytes)
# complex256 32

e = b + a
print(e.dtype, e.nbytes)
# complex256 32

print(d == e)
# True
```

---

Eventually, you may want to compute `z0` with NumPy's higher precision data types, if that precision is available and it is critical to your result.

Note that [this table](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types) would be your starting point to see how NumPy maps Python data types.

---

## Note on Floating Point information

Unfortunately, you [cannot easily get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8216088/5218354) the information on the number of bits for the different data types that Python uses.

You can get some information with [`sys.getsizeof()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) but this will have information on the memory usage of the Python object, which includes Python's book-keeping information.

However, you can get some information on Python's `float` with [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```py
import sys


a = 10+1.0j
print(sys.float_info)
# sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Similarly, you can get NumPy floating-point information with [`np.finfo()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) (note that when feeding complex datatypes, you get the information on the underlying floats):

```py
for dtype in (float, np.float_, np.double, np.cdouble, np.longdouble, np.clongdouble):
    print(np.finfo(dtype))
```

```
Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float128
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  18   resolution = 1e-18
machep =    -63   eps =        1.084202172485504434e-19
negep =     -64   epsneg =     5.42101086242752217e-20
minexp = -16382   tiny =       3.3621031431120935063e-4932
maxexp =  16384   max =        1.189731495357231765e+4932
nexp =       15   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------

Machine parameters for float128
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  18   resolution = 1e-18
machep =    -63   eps =        1.084202172485504434e-19
negep =     -64   epsneg =     5.42101086242752217e-20
minexp = -16382   tiny =       3.3621031431120935063e-4932
maxexp =  16384   max =        1.189731495357231765e+4932
nexp =       15   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual precision of the `long double` type is [platform and compiler dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#Implementations).

Comment: NumPy's `float128` is not platform-independent; see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023995/1217358

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I have updated my answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Python’s floating-point numbers are usually 64-bit floating-point numbers, nearly equivalent to np.float64.

we can actually see this from the basic types in the docs here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

So Python alone is satisfactory for accuracy.

Comment: Nearly equivalent?  I'd say exactly equivalent, unless provided with evidence to the contrary.

Comment: "So Python alone is satisfactory for acuracy." why do you say so? The dtype of the matrices involved in the calculation use twice the number of bits of Python's floats.

Comment: @norok2,  it is **from the numpy docs** (right at the bottom) which i have provided a link to.

Comment: in the docs I read clongdouble to be two extended-float which is 128 bit.

Comment: @MarkRansom,  you may well be right...  although, there must have be a reason that the word "nearly" was specifically used.

Comment: Probably just so nobody would file a bug if they noticed a difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The non-equivalence they're referring to is most likely in things like edge case behavior, methods supported, and broadcasting behavior, not in floating point representation format. For example, `1.0/0.0` will raise a ZeroDivisionError, while `numpy.float64(1.0)/numpy.float64(0.0)` will issue a warning and return an infinity value under default settings.